# Microfocus Cobol Animator Debugger

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I am using the Microfocus animator tool and I am able to debug the cobol executable from putty. The cobol animator tool converts the executable into source code and highlights the current executing statement.

But , the animator and the putty session hangs when it reaches the "GOBACK" statement in Cobol.

Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: When next you pop by, I think you should give Logan an Upvote (you have the points now) and an Accept for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried pressing ESC and exiting the debugger? I know when I use it, it always stops at the end of the program, and you have to press ESC first, then say Yes to stop or Detatch.

I found this on the microfocus site. Check your settings and variables to see if they match what it says. [Animator and Putty](http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=34180)

Update - It looks like the link no longer works. I wonder if kb.microfocus.com changed their address for the url. The link was just to the KB of microfous.com.

Comment: THe cobol animator hangs the putty session itself.. So nothing will work. I have to exit the putty and relogin again. It shows an error that "parent module not present in the current drive/directory

Comment: Does animator pop up into a new window when you start debugging or does it launch in your current shell window? It should launch another window, which it sounds like may be the issue. I found a link that tells you everything you need to set up animator with putty. Try this and see if it works. http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=34180

Comment: When I am using animator , it opens in the same window... I will go through the link you provided and update you with the results

Comment: The link is dead.